# How to resolve implicitly has an 'any' type error in TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

I'm working with typescript react and react hooks for the first time and I couldn't figure out the error on the type checking. This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

export function HomePage(props: HomePageProps) {
  const [userName, setUsername] = useState<string>('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('')
```

And below are the error messages:

```
web/src/view/page/HomePage.tsx(13,21): error TS7006: Parameter 'username' implicitly has an 'any' type.
web/src/view/page/HomePage.tsx(13,31): error TS7006: Parameter 'email' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: uh, that is odd.. if your IDE supports intelli-sense what shows up when you hover over `useState`?  if you use `React.useState` instead does it give the same error? also error message says `username` and the code you have is `userName` so are you sure this is the correct code that is breaking?

Comment: I believe you need to install `@types/react` if you have not already, although I don't think that would cause *implicit* `any` errors.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Omg thank you so much! I fixed it!